# Java and GlassFish Deployment error: Project is currently archive deployed

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

When I run my web application NetBeans gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\Gamer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyWebApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Project is currently archive deployed. Undeploy this project and redeploy it to take advantage of directory deployment.
See the server log for details.
```

I did redeploy and still same

The code on the 1045th row is:

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

The app is deployed on the GlassFish server but I don't know what's archive deployed.

Comment: What glassfish and netbeans version do you have?

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 and glassfish 4.1.1

Comment: Try to manually undeploying it using the Glassfish admin console. This is for an older version but maybe will help http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Deployment-error-Project-is-currently-archive-deployed-td2965466.html

Comment: I tried but still same error Deployment error: Project is currently archive deployed. Undeploy this project and redeploy it to take advantage of directory deployment.
See the server log for details.